# trying to make a abstract class with GOval and graphics that extends to a normal class

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I was given a task to make three abstract methods and put all them in one abstract class that extends to a normal class. One that was a circle, second a colored parellelogram, and a curved graphic entity.
So the the Idea I came up was a pizza maker. Have three toppings be the smaller abstract classes but I can wrap head around it to make it work. I see alot examples of abstract but they don't really give me what I need for this. The problem came I made the black circle class and I can't access from another class. It can't instantiate blackCircle and I tired make putting on a different class that didn't work. I haven't made any process the last couple hours due to time so I wondering if someone can point me in the right direction what I'm doing wrong.

my main class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import acm.graphics.*;

import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import testingField.ToppingsMenu.toppings;
import testingField.designFactory.Shape;

public class pizzaFactory extends GraphicsProgram {
public void init(){
theDough();
theSauce();

addMouseListeners();

}
public static void main(String[] args){
    toppings blackCircle = new blackCircle;
    // where the problem begins//
}
public void theDough(){
    dough = new GOval (100,100,200,200);
    dough.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    dough.setFilled(true);
    add(dough);
}
public void theSauce(){
    sauce = new GOval (100,100,180,180);
    sauce.setColor(Color.RED);
    sauce.setFilled(true);
    add(sauce);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
   {
     last = new GPoint(e.getPoint());
     gobj = getElementAt(last);
   }

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
   {
       if (gobj != null) {
             gobj.move(e.getX() - last.getX(), e.getY() - last.getY());
             last = new GPoint(e.getPoint());
          }
   }

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
   {
       if (gobj != null) gobj.sendToFront();
   }

private GObject gobj;
private GPoint last;
private GOval dough;
private GOval sauce;
  }
```

my abstract class

```
 import java.awt.Color;

 import acm.graphics.*;
 import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
 import testingField.ToppingsMenu.toppings;

  public abstract class blackCircle extends GraphicsProgram implements 
 toppings {

public void init(){
    blackCircle = new GOval (radius,radius,radius,radius);
    blackCircle.setColor(Color.black);
    blackCircle.setFilled(true);
    add(blackCircle);
}


public void draw() {
      System.out.println("Olives");
      init();
   }
private  GOval blackCircle;
private int radius = 10;
}
```

my interface

```
public class ToppingsMenu {
public interface toppings {
    abstract void draw();

}
}
```

Comment: `toppings blackCircle = new blackCircle;` <- First of all, that is not how you instantiate the class at all. Second, abstract classes cannot be instantiated, because they are "partial" classes and are meant to be missing some parts which other - "normal", as you said, - classes fill in when they are made. Take a step back and look at your program again, without looking at what is inside you methods.

Comment: That doesn't give much to go on, can you give me a good example?

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/cielavenir/procon/blob/master/hackerrank/java-abstract-class.java